# How to display specific records in drop down list in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown, yii2-basic-app

I am using yii2 basic.

I have an auth-item table with full with 2 roles and remaining are permissions:

1. admin
2. fieldofficer
3. createGroup
4. updateGroup
5. viewGroup
6. deleteGroup

Here **admin** and **fieldofficer** are **roles**  and others are **permissions**

Now in auth_assignment crud, while selecting item_name, I have dropdown populated with all auth_item.

But I want to display only admin and fieldofficer in drop down list?

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your drop down on type-attribute.

Your auth_item table has a column/attribute called type that equals 1 or 2. 1 is for roles and 2 for permissions. Please check corresponding model \yii\rbac\Item with constants TYPE_ROLE and TYPE_PERMISSION.

Answer (score 0):

In `AuthItem` table:

```
use yii\rbac\Item;

public static function getRoleList()
{
    return self::find()->select('name')->where(['type' => Item::TYPE_ROLE])->indexBy('name')->column();
}
```

**DropDown**

```
<?= $form->field($modelName, 'field_name')->dropDownList(AuthItem::getRoleList(), ['prompt' => '--- Select Role ---']) ?>
```